# firefox not working after trying to dowload firefox 34.0.5

Tags: firefox, error-handling, vmware-workstation

I use the VMware Workstation to use Ubuntu on Windows.
The current version of Firefox was 31.0 and the Mozilla Firefox download download page said that this was the current version! (34.0.5 is the latest , that was what I knew)
So i tried to download 34.0.5 using this webpage (32-bit((I have a 64 bit windows laptop, but my VMware Workstation could only handle 32-bit) http://linuxg.net/firefox-34-0-5-has-been-released-how-to-install-firefox-34-0-5-on-the-most-popular-linux-systems/
it didn't work. I checked through my commands and they were correct.
And so this appeared in the terminal:

```
aayush@ubuntu:~$ firefox
bash: /usr/bin/firefox: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

The firefox button just kept on loading and nothing happened

A new firefox 34.0.5 file had been created, so I removed it but nothing happened .
What can i do??!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're using Ubuntu 14.04 and had the trusty-updates repo activated, you could upgrade to Firefox 34.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 with `sudo apt-get install firefox` (after `apt-get update` -ing).

I don't know exactly what you did to your system, but if you extracted a tar archive to some folders & changed links & stuff, you should probably reverse & undo whatever you did, then use the regular/official Ubuntu repo & update the regular way.

Installing by downloading the binaries straight from mozilla can work, usually, but it's far easier & usually more stable to use the official repos, built & tested for Ubuntu.